# Send emails from Pickup folder Or process .EML files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

I am using MVCMailer plugin for generating emails from my asp.net MVC3 application and the settings is to save mails in PickupDirectory and the application is saving the E-mail type files inside the directroy .(.eml files in the directory)

```
<smtp from="mygmailid@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <network host="localhost:65436" />
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\MyAppFolder\mailPickup"/>
</smtp>
```

And this is the controler action creating the email file inside C:\MyAppFolder\mailPickup

```
 public ActionResult About()
    {
        UserMailer.Welcome().Send(); //Send() extension method: using Mvc.Mailer
        return View();
    }
```

The question is now how can i send the mail to the end user from this directory? Do i need to write custom scripts to send it or all the Email files will be delivered automatically?

If i have to write the scripts how can i do this? any sampleS?

Comment: You should setup [SMTP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(v=ws.10).aspx) on your IIS. Make sure you installed SMTP server as web server feature.

Comment: And SMTP should use the same pickup directory. Generally using a pickup directory is a lot faster - for the website - than pushing to a smtp server, so it is kind of a preferred method. Does not stop the need for a smtp server, though.

Comment: I set the SMTP email as store email in Pickup directory optionand saved and restarted IIS from IIS Manager. BUt still my emails are not sending with the config values as per question. @MaxBrodin How can i make sure i installed SMTP server as web server feature?

Comment: What OS do you use? For server versions of Windows the SMTP server is not installed by default. SMTP can be added through the Features Summary area of the Server Manager tool.

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 and i can see SMTP email under Features section as well and what i did is  Store e-mail in pickup directory: to store e-mails in a file location on disk for later delivery by an application such as an ASP.NET application, or by a user, such as an administrator.And eml files are created in specified folder

Comment: My question is how can i processs the generated eml file. Will that be processed automatically or do i need to do anyhing extra?